# Jquery plugin to work with frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

I'm looking for jquery plugin for easy cross-browser frame processing.
For example, I have following use cases:

```
$('#my-frame').ready(...);
$('#my-frame').scroll(...);
var x = $('#my-frame').scrollTop();
```

Could you suggest good plugin for frame processing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean by "cross-browser frame processing", but if you want jQuery or javascript at all to modify contents of frames that contain pages from different hosts - that is not possible.

Comment: I'm meaning "same host" case.

Answer (score 0):

$() accepts a second parameter "context", this may be a node, but also a document(e.g. the document inside  a frame )

By this you don't need a plugin.

The call may look like

```
$('body',$('#my-frame')[0].contentDocument)
```

Comment: Are you sure `$($('#my-frame')[0].contentDocument).scrollTop()` is cross-browser? I'm asking because iframe contentDocument is not cross-browser and we should use `elem.contentDocument || elem.contentWindow.document` in `contents()` function of jquery.

Comment: For example `$($('#my-frame')[0].contentDocument).scroll(function(){...});` does not work in IE, but works in FF. 
But `$($('#my-frame')[0].contentWindow).scroll(function () { ... });` works in FF and IE.

Comment: And you need a plugin for this simple condition?